# How can i create dynamic array in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

please help me how can i create dynamic array in codeigniter with foreachloop.

In dynamic array we need id as index and name as value.

for example:

```
 $options = array(
                              'DCA'         => 'DCA',
                              'DTP'           => 'DTP',
                              'ADCA'         => 'ADCA',
                              'TALLY'        => 'TALLY',
                              'C'           => 'C',
                              'C++'         => 'C++',
                              'DCA+DTP'     => 'DCA + DTP',
                              'DTP+TALLY'     => 'DTP + TALLY',
                              'DCA+TALLY'         => 'DCA + TALLY',
                              'Basic-Computer' => 'Basic Computer',
                               'hin_type' => 'Hindi Typing',
                                'eng_type' => 'English Typing',
                                 'hin+eng' => 'Hindi and English Typing',
                      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I have found an answer of that question. Simply I am using foreachloop

```
$result = array();
foreach($data as $key = $value)
{
   $result['$key'] = $value['name'];
}
print_r($result);
```

the above code prints $result in array format